# error TS2339: Property 'partition' does not exist on type 'Observable<boolean>'

Tags: angular, observable, rxjs5, rxjs6, angular8

Previously I was using rxjs-5 and I was using observable.partition as follows:

```
const [isTiming$, isNotTiming$] = this.store.select(state => state.tetris.isTiming)
        .partition(value => value);
```

After upgrade `angular` to `8` `rxjs` got upgraded to `rxjs-6` which started throwing following error:

```
 providers/timer.provider.ts(27,5): error TS2339: Property 'partition' does not exist on type 'Observable<boolean>'.
```

when I checked in older rxjs implementation it was implemented as follows:

```
  import { Observable } from '../Observable';
  import { partition as higherOrder } from '../operators/partition';
  /**
   * Splits the source Observable into two, one with values that satisfy a
   * predicate, and another with values that don't satisfy the predicate.
   */
   export function partition<T>(this: Observable<T>, predicate: (value: T, index: number) => boolean, thisArg?: any): [Observable<T>, Observable<T>] {
    return higherOrder(predicate, thisArg)(this);
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After seeing [github conversion](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3797)

I think we should deprecate the partition operator and remove it for v7.

Reasons:

- Not really an operator: partition isn't really an "operator" in that it returns [Observable, Observable] rather than Observable. This means it doesn't compose via pipe like the others.
- Easy to replace with filter: partition is easily replaced with the much more widely known filter operator. As partition is effectively the same thing as: `const partition = (predicate) => [source.pipe(filter(predicate)), source.pipe(filter((x, i) => !predicate(x, i)))]`

in your case:

```
import {filter} = "rxjs/operators"
const source = this.store.select(state => state.tetris.isTiming);
const partition = (predicate) => [source.pipe(filter(predicate)), source.pipe(filter((x, i) => !predicate(x, i)))]

const [isTiming$, isNotTiming$] = partition(value => value);
```

- Rarely used: It's little used, by any code survey I've taken (within thousands of lines of code that I know use RxJS)

Answer (score 2):

I guest you should use Observable method `pipe`, something like this :

```
const [isTiming$, isNotTiming$] = this.store.select(state => state.tetris.isTiming)
        .pipe(
            partition(value => value);
        )
```