# error TS2339: Property 'timer' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'. 'switchMap' and 'takeUntil' breaks the flow

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Moved to angular8, rxjs6. timer, switchMap, combineLatest, methods breaking. Trying to solve combineLatest or Timer propeties breaks the flow of the other properties.

Initialy code breaks at Partition, fixed it [error TS2339: Property 'partition' does not exist on type 'Observable<boolean>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56609155/error-ts2339-property-partition-does-not-exist-on-type-observableboolean)

```
      init(): void {
        const source = this.store.select(state => state.tether.isTiming);
        const partition = (predicate) => [source.pipe(filter(predicate)), source.pipe(filter((x, i) => !predicate(x, i)))]

        const [isTiming$, isNotTiming$] = partition(value => value);

        const partialInterval$ = this.store.select(state => state.tether.partialInterval);
        const interval$ = this.store.select(state => state.tether.interval);


                  isTiming$
        .combineLatest(interval$, (isTiming, interval) => interval)
        .withLatestFrom(partialInterval$)
        .switchMap(([interval, partialInterval]) => {
            return timer(partialInterval, interval)
                .takeUntil(isNotTiming$);
        })
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.store.dispatch(softDrop(true));
        });

      }
```

rewriting this with piping breaks.

```
    isTiming$
        .combineLatest(interval$, (isTiming, interval) => interval)
        .withLatestFrom(partialInterval$)
        .switchMap(([interval, partialInterval]) => {
            return timer(partialInterval, interval)
                .takeUntil(isNotTiming$);
        })
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.store.dispatch(softDrop(true));
        });
```

error TS2339: Property 'timer' does not exist on type 'typeof Observable'.

error TS2339: Property 'combineLatest' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

error TS2339: Property 'withLatestFrom' does not exist on type 'Observable'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now in new RX-6 `timer` and `combineLatest` is now part of rxjs core module and `withLatestFrom` is available under `rxjs/operators` module

See: [timer, combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) and [withLatestFrom](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/withlatestfrom.html)

In your case following implementation will work

```
init(): void {
    const source = this.store.select(state => state.tetris.isTiming);
    const partition = (predicate) => [source.pipe(filter(predicate)), source.pipe(filter((x, i) => !predicate(x, i)))]

    const [isTiming$, isNotTiming$] = partition(value => value);

        const partialInterval$ = this.store.select(state => state.tetris.partialInterval);
        const interval$ = this.store.select(state => state.tetris.interval);


            combineLatest(interval$, (isTiming, interval) => interval).pipe(
              withLatestFrom(partialInterval$), switchMap(([interval, partialInterval]) => {
          return timer(partialInterval, 1000).pipe(takeUntil(isNotTiming$));
      })
        )
            .subscribe(() => {
                this.store.dispatch(softDrop(true));
            });

    }
```